# Will Sarah Connor still die of Leukemia?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

So Sarah and Kyle managed to save the world from judgement day in Terminator Genisys. They destroyed Genisys/Skynet.

I just remembered that John mentions to Kate and Terminator (Arnold) in Terminator: Rise of Machines while in the graveyard, that his mother died of Leukemia.

After Genisys, Sarah now lives a normal life but does that change the way she dies?
Or was John trying to hide the real reason for his mother's death by making up a story of cancer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in Sarah's genes to develop leukemia. Unless someone with that prior knowledge (like Pops) warns Sarah and she gets it treated early on, Sarah will die if leukemia when she hits that age.

Comment: So john did not just make up this story to cover up her death. I may have not seen one of the terminator movies so i am confused if i missed anything about it. But if she really did die of Leukemia in that movie, than that would remain unchanged. Tricky thing this time-travel. May be they can travel in future to see if there is any treatment for the disease and cure it. That's just my imagination, not related to the question though.

Comment: John has no reason to make that story up, at least nothing evident from the movies. In fact John is surprised to see guns in her coffin, he doesn't expect her body to not be there. Sarah from genisys has travelled forward to the year 2017 hence she may not die of leukemia because she may get an early warning and also medical aid would be more advanced by the time she gets leukemia. Did the answer help btw?